# How transfer iTunes playlists from two computers to same iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

How transfer iTunes playlists from two computers to same iPhone?
I have iTunes libraries on several different computers (Home, Work, Laptops etc.  All use the same Apple iTunes account and password. I now find that I cannot create playlists in the different libraries and then copy it to my iPhone.  I am fairly sure I used to be able to do this.  When I try to set the iPhone to "Manually manage music and videos" on a second machine, I get a message saying "An iPhone can be synched with only one iTunes library at a time.  ..."replaces the contents of the this iPhone with contents of the iTunes library".   I am afraid to click "Erase and Synch" even thought I have "Manually manage..." checked.    Suggestions?  Comments?

Answer (score 1):

Why not review the manually manage support article and refine your question with the specific steps you took to set things up.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1535

In a nutshell - you connect the iPod to Computer A and drag in the playlists you want. Then you disconnect it and repeat on the second computer.